# Selecionar elementos de todas as window.frames e aplicar eventos

Tags: javascript, html, eventos, svg, frames

**Como eu posso selecionar e manipular elementos de todas as window.frames que estão sendo geradas por cada SVG dentro de uma tag `<object>` que coloco na página ?**

Estou querendo adicionar eventos `click()` nos elementos `<g>` dos arquivos **.svg** carregados dinamicamente em divs, dentro do elemento [object](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-object-element) através do atributo `data` . Os arquivos e a página índex estão no mesmo domínio.

Por hora estou conseguindo manipular os elementos somente quando é dado a índice da [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window) aonde o svg está. Pensei ser possível tudo carregar na janela principal, para aproveitar um único documento.

mas pelo visto...

**[W3.org 13.5 Notes on embedded documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.1)**

> " An embedded document is entirely independent of the document in which it is embedded "

*"Um documento incorporado é totalmente independente do documento em que está incorporado"*

**[W3School - The Window Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp)**

> " If a document contain frames ( tags), the browser creates one window object for the HTML document, and one additional window object for each frame."

*"Se um documento contiver quadros (tags), o navegador cria um objeto de janela para o documento HTML e um objeto de janela adicional para cada quadro".*

Essa imagem é o cenário do painel DOM

*para cada svg adicionado aparece um índice novo e uma `Window`.*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O índex está assim

*aonde cada Window no painel DOM é o caminho que está sendo atribuído no attr `data`.*

```html
<!-- Html reduzido só para mostrar em que posição do
Html ele está e como estão seus atributos, lembrando
que o attr data recebe um php:pdo query e a div .svg
é gerado dinamicamente através de um condição e echo
php -->

<html> 
 <head>
   <script/> 
 </head>     
      
      <body>
          
          <div></div>
          <div></div>...

       <?php 

         if($condicao){
        
          echo " 
          
          <div class='svg'>

          <object id='svg_id' data= ' ".$evt['local']." ' type='image/svg+xml' ></object>

          </div>";
        
        ?>
        
</html>
```

A maneira que estou acessando os elementos do SVG é a seguinte, fiz tanto com `Javascript` e também tentei com `Jquery`.

**ps:** Jquery não vou postar pois o código é baseado nos javascript, ao invés do contentDocument tentei com contents() mas no fim, mesmo com Jquery, só conseguia quando misturava o contentDocument junto com um índice da Window.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para selecionar todos os elementos dos `SVG` e das `Window` eu tentei utilizar seletores sempre tentando suas funções `all` ou `(*)`. Mas no fim, sempre que usava algum seletor desse eu fico preso ao ter que escolher um índice da Window.

Aproveitando, o que significa esse `#Document` ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Repare que o `<g>` de cima, do SVG Um, está recebendo os eventos, e o de baixo, SVG Dois, não, gostaria que todos estivessem, e futuramente os demais SVG inseridos.*

Comment: Li toda a pergunta e percebi que o problema não é relacionado ao que diz o título (posso estar enganado) nem em relação à manipulação de SVG. Não seria apenas ao fato de que os novos elementos não estão recebendo o click do evento?

Comment: Hmm talvez deveria focar a pergunta mais nessa questão dos frames ? Os elementos não recebem o evento talvez, por eu não saber como acessar todos frames de uma vez ?  minha dúvida está ai, como manipular elementos svgs nessas situações que são gerados vários frames, funcionando só quando é especificado o índice do frame que está o SVG a receber os elementos... Se tiver sugestões por favor edite! :)

Comment: Dá uma olha nesse JSFiddle para ter uma idéia. Quando novos elementos são adicionados na página, é preciso recriar o evento: https://jsfiddle.net/9n0hy6p8/

Comment: @dvd Era exatamente isso que eu não estava enxergando e entendendo, uau!